# ASP.NET MVC - View is not returned until asynchonous emails sending is completed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, smtp

I have a Contact page where users are able to complete a form which is sent to a Controller.
This Controller generates an email based on form data and returns a success view to the user.
The problem is that the success view is not displayed until email sending is completed, but this takes too much time (around 30 seconds), which is not acceptable.

First, I tried **synchronous sending**:

```
public ActionResult Contact(string TestMessage)
{
    // Prepare SMTP client
    SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient()
    {
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        EnableSsl = true,
        Host = "smtp.test.com",
        Port = 587,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("smtpuser", "smtppass")
    };

    // Prepare message
    MailMessage MailMessage = new MailMessage()
    {
        From = new MailAddress("sender@mydomain.com"),
        Subject = "Test",
        BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
        SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    };
    MailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient@mydomain.com"));
    MailMessage.Body = TestMessage;

    // Send mail
    Client.Send(MailMessage);

    // Return success view
    return View("ContactSuccess");
}
```

After that I tried **asynchonous sending**. I have spent hours reading StackOverflow questions to find the miracle solution. But the result is always the same, page is still waiting for email sending to be completed.

**Asynchronous attempt 1**

```
// Send mail
Client.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    Client.Dispose();
    MailMessage.Dispose();
};
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
    Client.SendAsync(MailMessage, Tuple.Create(Client, MailMessage)));
```

**Asynchronous attempt 2**

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => SendViaAsync(MailMessage));
```

**Asynchronous attempt 3**

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(
    cancellationToken => Client.Send(MailMessage)
    );
```

**Asynchronous attempt 4**

```
// Send mail
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(SendViaAsync, MailMessage);
```

With added methods:

```
private void SendViaAsync(object MailMessageObject)
{
    MailMessage MailMessage = (MailMessage)MailMessageObject;

    SmtpClient Client = Utilities.CreateEmailClient();
    Client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SmtpClient_SendCompleted);
    Client.Send(MailMessage);
}

void SmtpClient_SendCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage mail = e.UserState as MailMessage;
    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error != null)
    {
       // error handling
    }
}
```

**Asynchronous attempt 5**

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Contact(string TestMessage)
// ...
// Send mail
await SendEmail(MailMessage);
```

With added method:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SendEmail(MailMessage MailMessage)
{
    SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient()
    {
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        EnableSsl = true,
        Host = "smtp.test.com",
        Port = 587,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("smtpuser", "smtppass")
    };

    await Client.SendMailAsync(MailMessage);
}
```

Please note that when locally testing, email is sent immediately (in both synchronous or asynchronous modes). In production only, it takes around 30 seconds. So maybe there is something like an antivirus scan in my hosting provider, but anyway I can't figure out why the success view is not sent until mail sending is completed.

I am desperate. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: At least your second attempt `Task.Run(() => SendViaAsync(MailMessage))` should work. Unless it is the creation of the `MailMessage` object that causes the delay. Could you try a `Task.Run` version that does internally everything related to the sending of the message?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried what you said before finding the solution, please see below.

Answer (score 2):

Any attempts with `await` will definitely fail to accomplish what you want by definition. But in general I don't think it's wise to have an asp.net page starting up processes which may keep running beyond the lifetime of the request. And perhaps that's exactly what's happening internally: ASP.Net not finalising the request until all its child processes have finished.

Personally, I would de-couple the process altogether. First because each part will be simpler to maintain, but also because it's more secure.

Have your application dump the email, or the data to build the email, into a queue of sorts. This could be a database, a file, a folder or whatever, but some temporary storage.

Then develop a background service or daemon, which reads this queue and processes the emails. It will end up being more flexible, more scalable and safer.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about your solution, before understanding what was the real problem, please see below.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have understood the problem. I can't believe it.

I didn't mention it in my bug reproduction, but I am using Google reCAPTCHA in the contact form.
It seems that reCAPTCHA is very slow in production environment!
After deactivating it, it appears that email is immediately sent.
Now, I just have to replace reCAPTCHA with a faster checking mecanism.

Sorry for disturbance, I hope this will help some of us later. At least some asynchronous programming examples are listed here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a builtin functionality in asp net you can use it as easy as written below

```
  public ActionResult SendEmail(User user)
        {

            HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>
            {
                // Prepare SMTP client
                SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient()
                {
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    Host = "smtp.test.com",
                    Port = 587,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("smtpuser", "smtppass")
                };

                // Prepare message
                MailMessage MailMessage = new MailMessage()
                {
                    From = new MailAddress("sender@mydomain.com"),
                    Subject = "Test",
                    BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                    SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                };
                MailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient@mydomain.com"));
                MailMessage.Body = TestMessage;

                // Send mail
                Client.Send(MailMessage);
            });


            // Return success view
            return View("ContactSuccess");
        }
```

if you want to go over advance scenarios , like handling many background jobs you can use  [Hangfire](http://www.example.com/)  library

[this blog post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) will also help you solve your problem